# Operator on do indentation

Tags: haskell, monads, indentation, operator-precedence, backticks

`hindent` changed my code to:

```
do download i inputFile
   onException
     (callProcess (List.head args) (List.tail args))
     (removeFileIfExists name)
   `finally` removeFileIfExists inputFile
```

I can't determine if the `finally` applies to the rest of the `do` block, or just the state beginning `onException`. According to [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#Explicit_characters_in_place_of_indentation),

> If you see something unexpected in a list, like where, insert a
>   closing brace before instead of a semicolon.

I'm unsure if that rule is applying here.

Does the `` `finally` `` apply to the rest of the do, or just the last statement and why?

Comment: Finally takes (like all operators) lower precendence than functions, so it is `finally (onException (callProcess ...) (removeFileIfExists name)) (removeFileIfExists inputFile)`. `finally` is thus the main function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can find out using GHCi: writing

```
Prelude> let f = (>>)
Prelude> :{
Prelude| do print 5
Prelude|    print 4
Prelude|    `f` print 3
Prelude|    print 2
Prelude| :}
```

causes the following type error (not a parse error!)

```
<interactive>:12:8: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘(() -> IO ()) -> Integer -> IO b’
                  with actual type ‘IO ()’
    • The function ‘print’ is applied to three arguments,
      but its type ‘Integer -> IO ()’ has only one
      In the second argument of ‘f’, namely ‘print 3 print 2’
      In the expression:
        do { print 5;
             print 4 }
        `f` print 3 print 2
```

Looking at the list lines, we discover how GHCi parsed the code, which is printed with explicit braces-and-semicolons.

There, we see that the `` `f` `` part *closed* the `do` block! This makes the whole `do` block to be the first argument to `f`. Further, the next lines, no longer being in a block, now form a single expression `print 4 print 2` which is used as the second argument for `f`. This triggers a type error since it calls `print` with three arguments.

Indeed, the brace `}` was inserted before `` `f` `` because of the rule mentioned by the OP: when something does not parse in a block, we add `}` and continue.

Summarizing, if `` `f` `` is indented *more*, the block is parsed as

```
do print 5
   print 4 `f` print 3
   print 2
```

If `` `f` `` is indented *as* the previous line, or *less*, the block is parsed as

```
(do { print 5
    ; print 4 }) `f` print 3 print 2
```

I would suggest to avoid indenting `` `f` `` exactly as the previous line: it is better to indent it less, so that the parsing becomes obvious even to a human reader.

Answer (score 0):

**The following does not actually adress the code you posted, but the question you seemed to be asking**. It adresses the following code instead:

```
do download i inputFile
   onException
     (callProcess (List.head args) (List.tail args))
     (removeFileIfExists name)
   ░`finally` removeFileIfExists inputFile
```

[chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48991448/745903) adresses the actually posted code, with `` `finally` `` not indented any further than `download` and `onException`. I'd remark that this is bad style: when writing that, be sure to indent it *less*, i.e.

```
  do download i inputFile
     onException
       (callProcess (List.head args) (List.tail args))
       (removeFileIfExists name)
 `finally` removeFileIfExists inputFile
```

---

As Willem Van Onsem commented, function applications *always* take precedence before infix applications. This is true for both “true infix operators” like `+` or `>>=`, and for backtick-infixes... if fact there is no baked in distinction between these sorts of operators as far as precedence is concerned: for all infixes the precedence is determined by a fixity declaration, such as

```
infixl 6 +
infix 4 `elem`
```

The fixity is a number in the range 0..9, and fixity can be either left- right- or non-associative. If no fixity is declared (as with most named functions, whereas for symbol-infixes it's highly recommended to give a fixity declaration), the default `infixl 9` is used, i.e. basically the highest legal fixity you could manually assign.

OTOH, function application is *always* `infixl 10` as it were, i.e. it binds tigher than any infix, no matter how it's declared. So, your example is parsed as

```
do (download i inputFile)
   (  (onException
        (callProcess (List.head args) (List.tail args))
        (removeFileIfExists name))
    `finally`
      (removeFileIfExists inputFile) )
```

Comment: If I decrement `` `finally` ``, it's now against the entire `do` block?

Comment: You mean, if you decrease its indentation so it starts left of `download` and of `onException`? Yes, that would make it parse as ``(do {...}) `finally` (...)``.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, which was about how an operator interacts with the `do` construct

Comment: Quite right, I got side-tracked. Leaving this answer here nevertheless, with a header on top refering to the other one.