# Debug explicit characters due to indentation

Tags: haskell, syntax, indentation, ghc

Haskell [automatically inserts](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#Explicit_characters_in_place_of_indentation) semicolons and braces due to indentation. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48991448/149482), a type error is used to have `ghci` print the code with the semicolons and braces explicitly shown. How can I view code after these insertions without an error? I expect there should be something like `gcc`'s `-E` flag, which shows code after macro preprocessing.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat >> Hello.hs
main = do
    putStr "Hello, "
    putStrLn "World!"

$ ghc -ddump-ds Hello.hs   # ds for "desugar"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Hello.hs, Hello.o )

==================== Desugar (after optimization) ====================
Result size of Desugar (after optimization)
  = {terms: 18, types: 9, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}

-- RHS size: {terms: 8, types: 3, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
main :: IO ()
[LclIdX]
main
  = >>
      @ IO
      GHC.Base.$fMonadIO
      @ ()
      @ ()
      (putStr (GHC.CString.unpackCString# "Hello, "#))
      (putStrLn (GHC.CString.unpackCString# "World!"#))

-- RHS size: {terms: 2, types: 1, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
:Main.main :: IO ()
[LclIdX]
:Main.main = GHC.TopHandler.runMainIO @ () main

-- RHS size: {terms: 5, types: 0, coercions: 0, joins: 0/0}
Main.$trModule :: GHC.Types.Module
[LclIdX]
Main.$trModule
  = GHC.Types.Module
      (GHC.Types.TrNameS "main"#) (GHC.Types.TrNameS "Main"#)
```

I suspect that's a bit *too* expanded for your taste, but it certainly doesn't have the block-indentation anymore.